# why does my function with connector/c++ crash on the return line?

Tags: c++, mysql-connector, connector

this function crashes on the return line:

```
string questionmsg(string user, sql::Statement *stmt)
{

sql::ResultSet *res;// ...
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT questionmsg FROM `life-checker` WHERE `user` = '" + user + "';");
res->next();
string id = res->getString(1);

delete res;
delete stmt;

return id; //crash here - Unhandled exception Access violation
}
```

here is the main:

```
int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;

    // ...
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    cout<<"Connecting to database...\n";
con = driver->connect("tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306", "xxxxx_user", "xxxxx_pass!");
con->setSchema("mrhowtos_main");

stmt = con->createStatement();
// ...



cout << questionmsg("Nolan", stmt);




delete con;
cout<<"done\n";
system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I am going through the program step by step watching variables. The result of id = res->getString(1); is exactly what i expected, a small sentence. so I dont know why its crashing. one thing i noticed while watching the variables is after going over the delete res and stmt line. the variable values in the watch box dont change, like its not actually deleting them. But I dont know maybe that's how it's supposed to appear.

Comment: Is type `string` there `std::string`?

Comment: yes, i am using namespace std

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  You're deleting `stmt` twice.  Once in the function `questionmsg`, and once in `main`. Fix that and see if your problem disappears.

Comment: i removed the one in main. error no different.

Comment: put `delete res; delete stmt; with delete con; inside main function` after exiting from function questionmsg

Comment: the stmt and res only exist inside the function, if i put the delete statements in main they would be undeclared. I also need to have the qwry and take results in the function, for the purpose of the whole future application.

Answer (score 0):

are u sure you own the memory for res?
Also for string id, it could still point to the space you already released?

Comment: how does one tell if they own the memory for it or not?

Comment: turns out i had version conflicts